# How to find chart control under my toolbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

As you can see in my screenshots below, I don't have an option chart under my toolbox. I checked and seem to have the proper references in place. I don't see any option to add the chart control either. Please help. Tnks.

reference

[image: reference]

toolbox

[image: toolbox]

no option to add chart control

[image: option]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The References under Solution Explorer only refers to what you can use in code.  Toolbox items have to be added separately.  To do this, right-click inside the Toolbox and select `Choose Items...`.  In the dialog that appears select the tab referring to the type of control (in this case it looks like WPF).  Scroll through the list to find the controls you want to add, tick them and click OK.  The controls should now be available in the Toolbox.  You can add extra tabs/sections to the Toolbox with the `Add Tab` right-click option.

That's a good question - I needed to search for a solution when I first tried to add new controls to the Toolbox!

Hope this helps!  :)

Comment: Thanks. I kept making the mistake of clicking on the toolbox name instead of inside the toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use devexpress.. 
Install devexpress first.. 
After installing , restart you visual studio,, open a windows form application
and
Try devexpress..

Add " New Tab" in your tool box.
Right Click Tab and "Choose Items"
You can select dll files there. selec all related files and click ok
when you are done, just drag and drop chart control on you application, the reference will automatically updated.

Comment: The library is not the issue here as a chart control comes as part of WPF already.

Answer (score 2):

The Chart is not a standard feature control of .NET 3.5 although it can be installed from a separate download. It is only standard in .NET 4.0 or higher. It is Not available at all (no separate download) for .NET 3.0  and below!

If you can, do change your project to .NET 4.0 to make the Chart control present in the Toolbox and then be able to add it to your forms. I have learnt this the long way...

Comment: Just the answer I needed.